# Is it possible to add a username a password to a hostname in /etc/hosts?

Tags: macos, ubuntu

Is it possible to add a username a password to a hostname in `/etc/hosts`?

Like: `a.b.c.d     username:password@hostname`

Comment: No, `/etc/hosts` is used only to map an IP address to a name.

Comment: Welcome to the community. What have you tried so far? The hosts file is not like the `shadow` file where it could lead to corruption of the whole file if edited incorrectly or with a text editor. Also, this seems to be not quite the right place for this question, I think it belongs in SuperUser?

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out hoping to get a solution.

Comment: This is not a security question and you have accepted an answer to a cross-post of this on SuperUser.